# How to extract the citation metadata from scientific publications/books

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning, bibliography, citations

I am planning to create an application which involves extraction of citation metadata.By doing this, i'm planning to reduce the human effort taken to search for the cited information,and make it accessible easily(by automating that process).

So far,i have read various scientific papers,and found that FLUX-CiM(by Eli Cortez) has the highest efficiency out of all the existing models.Unfortunately, there is no existing implementation of it anywhere, and no details regarding the its implementation(usage of any libraries/Programming Language/any other algorithm) has been provided in that paper.

So i would like to know,if there is any implementation of it ,or if there is any existing application similar to the FLUX-CiM(i.e.unsupervised learning style,as it is more reliable). I am very new to machine learning, and i would like to know if there is any tutorials/starting point to learn about implementing my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the various tools, but AnyStyle seems to have the functionality you're looking for, and is machine-learning based.

- Repo: https://github.com/inukshuk/anystyle-parser
- Demo: http://anystyle.io/

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.It was helpful.Could you suggest me few more like that(if any).

Comment: Well, the AnyStyle website points to [ParsCit](http://aye.comp.nus.edu.sg/parsCit/) and [FreeCite](http://freecite.library.brown.edu/).

Comment: Thank you.Will look on to it.